# Filter a set of arrays by keeping numbers that exist in all the arrays only?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, sorting

I have two arrays full of ID's of objects and I only want to keep the ID's of the objects the exist in both arrays. Example:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1])
b = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6])
```

So ideal output from this would be an array that has searched through arrays a and b and gives me an array of only the objects that are present in both lists. Something similar to:

```
c = np.array([3, 4])
```

This array shows that the ID 3 and the ID 4 are present in both lists. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use arrays, since you want sets:

```
set(a) & set(b)
```

If you need the result in an array:

```
np.array(list(set(a) & set(b)))
```